# How to transform Symfony collection of multiple text box in single choice (select box)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

I have Task entity and suppose that each Task belongs to multiple Tag objects.

So in form by symfony documentation i want single dropdown instead of
I have Task entity and Tag entity relation ship one to many
similar to
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Now see My TaskType form

add('tags', 'collection', [
                    'type'       => new ChoiceListType(),
                    'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag'
                ]


}

?>

//Now see my ChoiceListType . php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addModelTransformer(new CollectionToChoice());
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'choice';
}
```

In my CollectionToChoice Transformer file in public transform method error
The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.

Comment: Yes Task and Tag have similar relation ship
 http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html as in link... So i get multiple Tags text box in collection But i want tags in single dropdown. In

Answer (score 0):

change the form so that tags is not a collections, but an "[entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)" field type

You can then use that field types options, to choose wether to display checkboxes, radios, or a (multiselect) dropdown

```
Element Type                          Expanded  Multiple
select tag                            false     false
select tag (with multiple attribute)  false     true
radio buttons                         true      false
checkboxes                            true      true
```

So in your case you would set expanded to false, and multiple to true